# Reducing vertical space in `align` environment locally

Tags: align, vertical-spacing

I wanted to reduce the vertical space between text and the first line in `align*` environment locally. But setting `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-28pt}` allows it to work globally (I think) and that's why next time when I use `align*`, the lines are getting overlapped.
How can I reduce the vertical spaces locally?
Additionally the `c.` numbered line is slightly right sided when I used `newpage`. How do I align the sentence to left margin of the page?

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\def\toright#1{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty13 
    \null\nobreak\hskip1em plus1fill\hbox{#1}}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\begin{document}
    Hence $\displaystyle L[t(3\sin 2t-2\cos
    2t)]=-\dfrac{d}{dp}\dfrac{6-2p}{p^2+4}=\dfrac{2(4+6p-p^2)}{(p^2+4)^2} $
    \newpage
    \textbf{c.} We know that \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-28pt}
    \begin{align*}
        L[\sin at]&=\dfrac{a}{p^2+a^2}\\
        \Longrightarrow  L[t^2\sin at]&=(-1)^2\dfrac{d^2}{dp^2}\dfrac{a}{p^2+a^2}=\dfrac{d}{dp}\dfrac{-2ap}{(p^2+a^2)^2}=\dfrac{2a(3p^2-a^2)}{(p^2+a^2)^3}\\
        \Longrightarrow  L[t^2e^{at}\sin at]&=\dfrac{2a(3(p-a)^2-a^2)}
        {((p-a)^2+a^2)^3} \quad[\text{by first shifting property}]\\
        &=\dfrac{2a(3p^2-6ap+2a^2)}{(p^2-2ap+2a^2)^3}
    \end{align*}
    text text\\
    \textbf{c.} Let $\displaystyle F(p)=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{3}{p+2}$. Therefore
    \begin{align*}
        &\dfrac{d}{dp} F(p)=\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{1+(\frac{3}{p+2})^2}.\dfrac{-3}{(p+2)^2}=\dfrac{-3}{(p+2)^2+9}\\
        \Longrightarrow\; &L^{-1}\left[\dfrac{d}{dp}
        F(p)\right]=
        -L^{-1}\left[\dfrac{3}{(p+2)^2+9}\right]=
        -e^{-2t}L^{-1}\left[\dfrac{3}{p^2+9}\right]\quad[\text{by first shifting property}]\\
        \Longrightarrow\; &(-1)tL^{-1}[F(p)]=-e^{-2t}\sin 3t\\
        \Longrightarrow\; &L^{-1}[F(p)]=\dfrac{1}{t}e^{-2t}\sin
        3t
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `\baselinestretch` to `2` is definitely too much (and it's not “double spacing”).

Better use dedicated packages such as `setspace` and `geometry` as I show below.

You also should avoid `align` when `equation` and `split` suffice.

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  a4paper,% <--- I guess you need it
  textwidth=18cm,
  textheight=21cm,
}

%\setstretch{2} % <--- too big
\doublespacing

\newcommand{\toright}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty13 
  \null\nobreak\hskip1em plus1fill\hbox{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Hence we can conclude that
\begin{equation*}
L[t(3\sin 2t-2\cos 2t)]=-\frac{d}{dp}\frac{6-2p}{p^2+4}=\frac{2(4+6p-p^2)}{(p^2+4)^2}
\end{equation*}

\noindent\textbf{c.}
We know that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
  L[\sin at]&=\frac{a}{p^2+a^2}\\
  \Longrightarrow
  L[t^2\sin at]&=(-1)^2\frac{d^2}{dp^2}\frac{a}{p^2+a^2}
                =\frac{d}{dp}\frac{-2ap}{(p^2+a^2)^2}
                =\frac{2a(3p^2-a^2)}{(p^2+a^2)^3}\\
  \Longrightarrow
  L[t^2e^{at}\sin at]&=\frac{2a(3(p-a)^2-a^2)}{((p-a)^2+a^2)^3}
                      \quad[\text{by first shifting property}]\\
                     &=\frac{2a(3p^2-6ap+2a^2)}{(p^2-2ap+2a^2)^3}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
text text

\noindent\textbf{c.}
Let $F(p)=\tan^{-1}\frac{3}{p+2}$. Therefore
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
  &\frac{d}{dp} F(p)=\frac{1}{1+(\frac{3}{p+2})^2}\cdot\frac{-3}{(p+2)^2}=\frac{-3}{(p+2)^2+9}\\
  \Longrightarrow\;
  &L^{-1}\left[\frac{d}{dp}F(p)\right]
   =-L^{-1}\left[\frac{3}{(p+2)^2+9}\right]
   =-e^{-2t}L^{-1}\left[\frac{3}{p^2+9}\right]
   \quad[\text{by first shifting property}]\\
  \Longrightarrow\;
  &(-1)tL^{-1}[F(p)]=-e^{-2t}\sin 3t\\
  \Longrightarrow\;
  &L^{-1}[F(p)]=\frac{1}{t}e^{-2t}\sin 3t
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I removed all occurrences of `\displaystyle` and also changed every `\dfrac` into `\frac`: you already have too distant lines and you don't want to increase the gap even more.

I find `\Longrightarrow` completely useless in that context.

Comment: I needed to lift up `L[sin at]` line in the same level as that of `c. We know that` such that next time when I use `align*`, it won't be effected.

Comment: @ManjoyDas No, trust me, you don't want it.

Comment: why `\Longrightarrow` is not needed here?